# Numbers extracted from Google Analytics API differ from numbers in the Google Analytics portal

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have extracted daily active Users, monthly active Users and Total users of our App from Google Analytics,  and wanted to show in our website using html/jss

In our code, we are using following api as mentioned on link :

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

```
function sel_ViewSelector() 
{
    gapi.client.request ({
    path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
    root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
    method: 'POST',
    body:  
       {         
            reportRequests:
                [
                    {  
                        viewId: 'xxxxxxxx',  
                        dateRanges: 
                            [
                                {
                                    startDate: 'yesterday',
                                    endDate: 'yesterday'
                                }  
                            ], 
                         metrics: 
                            [
                                {
                                    expression: 'ga:users'
                                }
                            ],
                    }  
                ]
       }
 })
}
```

The result which we are getting from this code, differs from that in google analytics portal using the same metrics.

For each section, the following are the parameters used :
DAU : Start date - yesterday, End date - yesterday
MAU : Start date - 30 days ago, End date - yesterday
Total users : Start date - From its launch date, End date - yesterday

But when we compare this with Google Analytics Portal using exact same parameters, most of the values differ by few thousands.

So can you tell us why there is a difference between these values.